# Pipe incoming email to a script on Windows IIS SMTP?

Tags: windows, iis, email, iis-6, smtp

I have a web application running on Windows IIS. This app has a database where each item has a unique key (1, 2, 3...), and a list of email addresses (among other things).

I would like users to send email to the server, using an email address that identifies the item, then have the server relay the message to the email addresses for that item. For example, if a user sends email to the following address:

```
item-75@myserver.example.com
```

Then the server would receive the email and pipe it to a script. The script would query the database for item 75 to get a list of email addresses, then re-send the email.

I could do this easily on a unix system using sendmail, but I have no idea if a similar setup can be accomplished on a Windows system (or if it would require additional software).

So the questions are:

- Can the server accept multiple on-demand email addresses like item-1, item-2, etc. without having to create an email account for each one?
- Can the server pipe the emails received from each of those addresses into a script? Or alternately can a script run periodically to check a file or file for new messages to process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS's SMTP component can't do anything else than relaying messages.
You need some other software to accomplish this.

Comment: If you found this answer useful, can you please give a vote to it? :-)